# Angular WSL2 Debug - gets Unable to launch browser: "(void 0) is not a constructor"

Tags: angular, debugging

I am trying to use VSCode on WSL2
Got a problem launching debug mode for my angular 15 app
Just had my WSL2 set up and uses VSCode without any problems
Evnironment:
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎11/‎8/‎2022
OS build    22621.1485
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22639.1000.0

my launch.json has: as per https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "type": "msedge",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "myangular on chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:4200",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
]
}
```

@angular/cli                    15.2.4
Version: 1.77.0 (user setup)
Commit: 7f329fe6c66b0f86ae1574c2911b681ad5a45d63
Date: 2023-03-29T10:02:16.981Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
Sandboxed: Yes

error received when trying the launch debugger (Unable to launch browser: "(void 0) is not a constructor")
any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it,
Ironically, it was in the WSL extension,after many trial and errors, re-install and clear %USER_PROFILE%/.vscode until got a fresh install, then it worked,
as soon as I installed WSL extension, it gave that error, uninstall it, the error is gone and Angular debugger kicked in.
it is ironic that VSCode should give the ultimate experience with WSL, I hope folks at VSCode will get a fix soon, we have faith in you guys!! ;)

Comment: I just realized it is 0.77.0 preview, so will give these guys a break! thanks.

Comment: Just released 0.78.0 of the WSL extension and it is all working great. thanks VSCode team!! good job! :)

Comment: I have exactly the same annoying problem, thanks for your research, but I have a question how to install version 0.78, I am not offered an update in the IDE to version 0.78 and when I uninstall the extension and try to reinstall it offers me 0.78.3 but it turns into 0.77 when I install. I tried downgrading the version but I get the same error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting!! I would uninstall/re-install VScode, remember they are two parts, client and server mode, or you can just try the Help->Check for update on VSCode main menu, that should trigger the update on the server, if that doesn't work then go to option 1 above!